# Yarn can't connect to Hadoop HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, connection-refused

I am running one of the examples (pi) that came with Hadoop. The program doesn't respond, as it looks like it gets no response back due to connection with HDFS maybe?

```
yarn jar hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar pi 10 100

16/07/27 06:32:38 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/07/27 06:32:38 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 10
16/07/27 06:32:38 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:10
16/07/27 06:32:38 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1469626018898_0001
16/07/27 06:32:39 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1469626018898_0001
16/07/27 06:32:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://IP_ADDRESS/proxy/application_14696260188001/
16/07/27 06:32:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1469626018898_0001
```

I do `telnet IP_ADDRESS 9000` and connection was successful.

I did already setup `hdfs-site.xml` with the following (to listen on both private and public addresses):

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-bind-host</name>
   <value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
```

And `core-site.xml` is setup with:

```
<property>
   <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
   <value>hdfs://IP_ADDRESS:9000</value>
</property>
```

Any ideas why Yarn job looks like its not reaching HDFS service and thereby not completing?

Comment: I don't see any error in your log, what do you mean by does not response ? The output just stops there until you kill it ? Can you check if the following folder was created in your HDFS: `/user/<USER>/QuasiMonteCarlo_<JOB_ID>/in`

Comment: The output you see is the output from the yarn client itself. For the actual Hadoop DFS log, I had opened the log for either datanode or namenode, or something like that (don't remember exactly which one) -- I think I remember it contained something like `connection refused.. retying after...`. The connection was to port `9000`.
Anyways, `hadoop dfs -ls /user/<USER>/QuasiMonteCarlo_<JOB_ID>/in` has `part0`, `part1` ... `part9`, each with 118 bytes of data.

Comment: It will be good to know when job is done, and the yarn client saying so, instead of user killing it because it never updated and stays at `INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1469626018898_0001`.